# Magento 2 modal z-index

Tags: javascript, magento, z-index, magento2

Is there a way to change the magento2 modal ( & modal overlay ) z-index, using their built in modal widget?

I've read all their docs and I couldn't find a nice way of doing it. But I do really need to increase the z-index...

I would rather change z-index for specific modals, but a global override of all modal widget z-index's would be OK too.

Here is the relevant part of my code ('zIndex' doesn't do anything)

Any ideas..?

```
var options = {
  type: 'popup',
  clickableOverlay: true,
  zIndex: 9995 
};
var modalPopup = modal(options, $('#modal_id'));
$('#modal_el').click(function() { modalPopup.openModal() });
```

Cheers! :)

Answer (score 3):

Fixed using css!

Set a custom class on the modal and set the z-index on this

```
var options = {
  ...
  modalClass: 'hi_z_index'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case editing a css class didnt resolve my issue and I find solution in adding a zIndex for modal form after init it.
So you can after it

```
var modalPopup = modal(options, $('#modal_id'));
```

add this

```
modalPopup.modal.zIndex(2000000001);
```

Comment: Please don't just answer with a code snippet. Try to explain what you are contributing to the topic or how your answer differs from the others.